# REST API Javascript - How to get an Id of document from a document library?

Tags: javascript, document-library, rest, file, response

How can I get an Id of document from a document library using JavaScript REST API?

I have an ajax call:
`http://site/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_NAME')/Files`

And it returns to me following data:
[image]

But I need an ID, how to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Try below API:

```
/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('url of doc library')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

Returns files properties along with associated list item properties.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using Angular 8 + pnpJS then below REST API can be used -

```
sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(`url of doc library`).files.expand("listItemAllFields").get()
```